# Полумосква / Полу-Москва

Tags: орфография, числительные, приставка, сложные-слова, слитно-раздельно-дефис

У меня есть три вопроса насчёт написания приставок *пол-* и *полу-* со словами, поскольку в учебнике, написанном Розенталем, эти случаи не обговорены.

1. Если мы пишем *полу-* с именем собственным, то мы всё равно пишем их вместе или нам нужен дефис? Например: *полумосква, полугеорг / полу-Москва, полу-Георг.*
2. Если мы *пол-* прибавляем к слову, которое не собственное имя, а нарицательное, и если оно уже через дефис пишется, то мы как в данном случае пишем это всё? Например: *пол-мини-юбки, пол-макси-ложки, пол-экс-мэра / полмини-юбки, полмакси-ложки, пол-эксмэра / полминиюбки, полмаксиложки, полэксмэра.*
3. Если мы *пол-* прибавляем к слову, которое уже имеет приставку, но эта приставка слитно пишется, то нам как, совы Вы мудрые, быть-то? Например: *пол-мегапропеллера, пол-зоопарка, пол-антигероя / полмегапропеллера, ползоопарка, полантигероя.*

Answer (score 3):

**Пол-** — это все-таки [числительное](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=52#pp52) (по Розенталю).

Мудрые совы порылись в словарях:
[**пол...**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB) (*половина*) — с последующим словом пишется через дефис (перед гласной, ***л***, перед прописной буквой, **перед дефисно пишущимся словом**) или слитно (в остальных случаях); с последующим сочетанием слов пишется раздельно;
[**полу...**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83) — первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно, но: *полу-конференц-зал.*

Приняли решение писать так:
*пол-мини-юбки, пол-экс-мэра, пол-антигероя, ползоопарка, полмегапропеллера* (сравните: полкилограмма, полкубометра);
*полу-Москва, полу-Георг* (слова с "полу" всегда пишутся слитно; но правила запрещают написание подряд в одном слове строчной и прописной буквы, поэтому указанные слова, думаю, должны писаться через дефис).

Нашли примеры:
*На ужасающие вопли козла сбежалось **ползоопарка** — и посетители, и сотрудники* (из статьи);
*Мощность взрыва метеорита "Челябинск" составила почти **полмегатонны*** (из статьи);
***«Полу-Нельсон»*** (фильм).

**Дополнение** (ПАС: [Корректирующие правила](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp151.php))

> § 151. Недопустимы слитные написания с одной прописной буквой в середине слова. Поэтому после начальной части слова, по основным правилам пишущейся слитно, — после приставки, первой части сложного или сложносокращенного слова — следует писать дефис, если вторая часть представляет собой собственное имя и потому пишется с прописной буквы.
> Примеры:
> <...> ***полу-Африка**, микро-Чернобыль, кино-Остап, нео-Робинзон, радио-Буратино, теле-Печорин, фото-Москва* (сложные слова)...

Comment: почему полмегапропеллера слитно, при пол-мини-юбки - вообще не понятно). Мегабайт и мегатонна - это единицы измерения, а мегапропеллер - нет.

Comment: Читаем внимательно еще раз: пол… – с последующим словом пишется через дефис — **пол-мини-юбки** (перед дефисно пишущимся словом) или слитно — **полмегапропеллера** (в остальных случаях);